# Broken my Debian install: 'sh' not found in PATH

Tags: bash, debian, kde, path, dpkg

I'm running a custom build of `Debian buster/sid`. I have broken a lot of things seemingly by mistakenly running `apt-get dist-upgrade` (I think that's what did it). So the desktop manager\desktop environment no longer loads at all and I just get a command-line shell.

Aptitude and apt-get are broken as is dpkg.

apt update, aptitude update and apt-get update fails and gives a lot of errors when attempted to run, however my /etc/apt/sources.list looks fine

```
deb http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib non-free
deb-src http:// ftp.ie.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib non free
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian sid main
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu sid main
```

errors on update like this:

```
Err:2 http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease
Couldn't execute /usr/bin/apt-key to check /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.ie.debian.org_debian_dists_experimental_InRelease
```

and

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success '/usr/bin/test -e /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service && /usr/bin/test -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket && /usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.PackageKit --object-path /org/freedesktop/PackageKit --timeout 4 --method org.freedesktop.PackageKit.StateHasChanged cache-update > /dev/null; /bin/echo > /dev/null'

E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

aptitude upgrade, apt upgrade or apt-get upgrade appear to be broken due to dpkg being broken

Dpkg gives this error:

```
dpkg: warning: 'sh' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected
```

however `echo $PATH` returns, which looks fine to me

```
/home/ferg/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

if I try `sh` I get

```
The program 'sh' is currently not installed. To run 'sh' please ask your administrator to install the package 'dash'
```

If I try `sudo apt-get install dash`

it tells me `dash is already the newest version (0.5.8-2.6)`

and if I continue

```
E: Sub-process /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true returned an error code (100)
E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg/preconfigure --apt || true
```

If I run `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` and comment out the line `DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbian/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";};`

then aptitude fails with

```
dpkg: warning: 'sh' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected
```

So I can't reinstall necessary packages to restore the system because dpkg (and therefore aptitude, apt-get, apt) are broken, seemingly because sh is not in my PATH. However all the correct directories are in my PATH. I'm assuming that fixing this issue with sh would allow dpkg and aptitude to work again but I'm wondering what precisely is the problem with sh?

Thank you in advance for any help.

---

Update:

```
ls -l /bin/bash
```

returns

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1099016 May 15  2017 /bin/bash
```

`ls -l /bin/sh` returns

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jun 28  2017 /bin/sh -> dash
```

`ls -l /bin/dash` returns

```
ls: cannot access 'bin/dash': No such file or directory
```

So /bin/sh seems to redirect to /bin/dash which has been deleted somehow?

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall dash` fails with:

```
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.    
E: Internal Error, No file name for dash:amd64
```

Running `sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh` and then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dash` fails with the same error as above.

Searching for this issue and variants of it on Google I've found numerous solutions related to the user's PATH and permissions, I've checked the files which relate to that including `/etc/sudoers` `/root/.bashrc` and `/root/.profile` and `/etc/profile`. In most of those cases the users were able to solve their issue by simply defining their path correctly (usually the `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin` directories were missing). As stated above my PATH seems to contain all the relevant directories whether I run `echo $PATH` normally or as root or `sudo echo $PATH`. Some users were also having issues with permissions or with `sudo` itself. I've also tried executing various `aptitude` `apt` and `apt-get` and `dpkg` commands as root using `sudo -i` which suggests that my issue is different.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /bin/??sh`? I would expect `/bin/sh` to be a symbolic link to either `bash` or `dash` - maybe the link just got broken or deleted?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for troubleshooting assistance, and does not contain an answerable question.  More details would be necessary for it to be answerable.  Please edit the question to include all relevant details (beginning by answering questions raised in comments).

Comment: Thanks for your input, do you have any suggestions as to how I could make this post more appropriate for this forum (eg; what information I'm missing that I should include?) Not being facetious but I'm relatively new to this site.

Comment: Hmmm, you *may* be able to work around the issue by running: `sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh` and *then* running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dash`.  So use `bash` as your `sh` shell temporarily.

Comment: `apt-get` prompts me to remove automatically installed packages `linux-image-4.8.0-1-amd64 linux-image-4.9.0-2-amd64 linux-image-4.9.0-3-amd64` using `sudo apt autoremove` I've ignored it up to this point as I assume it to be irrelevant and am somewhat less trusting of its judgement at the moment, but would you recommend I go ahead with that?

Comment: I'm not enough of a Debian expert to advise on that.  @steeldriver, by the way, your request for clarification was addressed.

Comment: The `autoremove` suggestion is really just housekeeping - IMHO you shouldn't worry about that for now. Meantime, try running  `sudo apt-get update` and **then** `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dash`

Comment: Well the update worked and I'm now running `sudo apt-get full-upgrade`. Its going to take a little while as its basically rebuilding my OS from the ground up at this point. Frustratingly I'm not really sure why `sudo apt-get update` worked on this occasion when it hadn't previously - perhaps because of using `bash` as my `sh` shell? But I was fairly certain I'd tried that already. That being said, its 4:40am here and I'm running on coffee so my memory is hardly infallible. Will post here when that's finished running.

Comment: Problem solved! The upgrade worked. Shall I append my solution to the original post or post it as an answer to my own question? (not fully certain how this site works yet) Many thanks to both of you for your input. Unfortunately I'm not sure how helpful this will be to others with the same problem as I can't be certain precisely what actions made the difference.

Comment: @Fearg you should add your own answer. I’ve given the reason for the failure below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Stephen Kitt I had encountered [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=888227) in `dash` which had broken `sh` (the Bourne shell) as `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash/` in my particular distribution.

Running `sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh` in order to point `sh` to `bash` and then running `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dash` followed by `sudo apt-get full-upgrade` solved the issue.

Comment: Life saver. I though I had to do a reinstall

Answer (score 10):

You were bitten by [a nasty bug in `dash`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=888227) which caused `/bin/sh` to be removed. This has since been fixed, which is why another `apt update` and `apt full-upgrade` fixed it (after restoring `/bin/sh` to point to `bash` presumably, your comments aren’t clear about that).